# auto scroll to top of page with safari on the ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, scroll, scrollto

I have a site for ipads and when they click on a certain page they are supposed to input their email. When they open, it automatically onfocuses to the input and the keyboard is brought up. The content of my page is only 373px because that is the viewable area above the keyboard. I'd like to prevent people from scrolling down below that point. Any ideas? Something that automatically scrolls them back when they try and scroll down..? Thanks

For further details: What I have is one page with 3 "slides". The first is 768px tall, when they click "enter your email to sign up" it takes them to slide 2. This is the slide I want to be only 373px tall and prevent scrolling. I've tried `$('#container').scrollTo( '768px', 500 ).css("height", "373px");`... this sets the height, but you're still able to scroll down and it just shows a big white box.

Thanks!

Comment: .. but what if they _want_ to scroll?

Comment: @sarnold, there's nothing down there to scroll to... i want it to be the effective bottom of the website... if they _want_ to scroll beyond the bottom of a website they can't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up make my page 768x1024 and disabling all scrolling (which is what I really wanted anyway) using this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.ontouchmove = function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If the page is small enough, they won't have scrollbars to use. The other thing is if they have trouble reading they may want to zoom in and scroll around your form. If you are still determined to do this you can set jquery's $(window).scroll to change scrolltop.

This is the code:

```
$(window).scroll( 
  function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
  }
);
```

You could probably use scrollto too, but I've never used it, so I don't want mess with it.

Comment: @truk, thanks... do you know of a way to adjust the size of the screen?

Comment: @Andypandy $(window).width(x) and $(window).height(y) should work, just change x and y of course.

Comment: @truk, can't seem to get this to work. any help is appreciated. thanks! `$('#button').click(function(){
       $('#container').scrollTo( '768px', 500 );
       $(window).height(373);`     The scrollTo part works

Comment: Assuming you ended that with }); try using window.resizeTo(width,height) instead...

Comment: @truk, yep sorry! i'm still pretty new w/jquery and javascript... can I use that with jquery?

Comment: Jquery is made of javascript, it's just a collection of functions, so yes.